# How to change the default number of words in LdaMulticore?

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

LDA shows 10 number of words in a topic by default. I want to increase these numbers by 15. I have tried "topn" and "num_words" keywords but both are giving me an error. how can I change this default behaviour?

```
model = models.LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=8,topn=15,chunksize=10000, passes=30,iterations=300)
```

Error is

```
    model = models.LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=8,topn=15,chunksize=10000, passes=30,iterations=300)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'topn'
```

Answer (score 2):

LDAs allocate as many words per topic as it sees fit so long as they pass its' threshold.  That means one topic might have 70 words where another could have 200.  You can view more words by printing them.  Try this:

```html
model.print_topics(8, 15)
```

Comment: @Sarai don't need it for just printing. i need this model somewhere else where i get number of words and it is giving me 10 words

Comment: @user3778289 where else are you using it?  Can you include the code?

Comment: for i in range(self.model.num_topics):
            topic_words[i] = []
            topic_words = self.model.get_terms(i)

Comment: like this i am accessing the topic words

Comment: @user3778289 Can you set i = [0, .., 30]

Comment: how i can set i=[0..30]? it is in the loop for number_topics

Comment: i solved this issue in this line   topic_words = self.model.get_terms(i,20)